# Difference between time stamp?

Tags: android, timestamp

How do I get the difference between the current time GMT and the time on the HMT based on the locale? (Both time and result in seconds).

This code return 0.

```
    long now = new Date().getTime()/1000;
    long currTime = getCurrentTimeStamp();
    long answer = (now - currTime);
    return answer;
```

Comment: The time is the same, its only the presentation that differs. I guess you are interested in the time zone difference? If so check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/15084967/233048

Comment: You can write answer and I check it as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is the same, its only the presentation that differs. I guess you are interested in the time zone difference? If so check out [Naveen Kumars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084967/233048) answer on how to get the timezone offset.