# Get timezone in GMT from Android devices

Tags: java, android, xamarin, timezone

The question seems quite simple but I would really appreciate the help. Search the internet many times.

Following is the code to get current timezone of Android Devices in GMT:

```
Java.Util.Calendar mCalendar = new Java.Util.GregorianCalendar();
Java.Util.TimeZone mTimeZone = mCalendar.TimeZone;
int mGMTOffset = mTimeZone.RawOffset + (mTimeZone.InDaylightTime(new Java.Util.Date()) ? mTimeZone.DSTSavings : 0);

string timeDiff = Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Hours.Convert(mGMTOffset, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Milliseconds).ToString();
```

Outputs:

> If Mobile time is GMT-03:00 Then timeDiff = -3
>
> If Mobile time is GMT+00:00 Then timeDiff = 0
>
> If Mobile time is GMT+05:00 Then timeDiff = 5
>
> If Mobile time is GMT+05:45 Then timeDiff = 5 (In Correct)

Issue comes when GMT is in decimal values like 5:45 shows 5.

What should  I do in these types of scenarios?

I took help from the following link
[How to get the timezone offset in GMT(Like GMT+7:00) from android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068113/how-to-get-the-timezone-offset-in-gmtlike-gmt700-from-android-device)

Comment: What is the desired result in the last case? A string of `5:45`?? Also what do you need the offset for? There may be an even better solution to what you’re really trying to obtain.

Comment: I’d use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getOffset()` to obtain a `ZoneOffset` object and then try to format it. To do this on not-very-new Android, you need to add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project first.

Comment: What better solutions are you talking about pal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using GregorianCalender you can get the timezone please check below
>   code

```
 Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 TimeZone mTimeZone = mCalendar.getTimeZone();
 int mGMTOffset = mTimeZone.getRawOffset();

 double sZone = (double) (TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(mGMTOffset,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
string timeDiff = sZone / 60;
```

Comment: With the help of this code I got 5.75 which I converted to form string like "GMT+05:45" 
Thanx buddy :)

Comment: Most Welcome @ZainSMJ.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    ZoneOffset currentOffset = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getOffset();
    System.out.println("Current offset is GMT" + currentOffset);
```

Running the above snippet today in Europe/Copenhagen time zone gave:

> Current offset is GMT+02:00

Denmark is at +01:00 during standard time and +02:00 during summer time (DST). We are currently using summer time, so the output is as expected and does take summer time into account.

Not knowing Xamarin I am giving you Java code and trusting you to convert.

If instead I set my JVM’s time zone to Asia/Kathmandu I get the offset you asked for:

> Current offset is GMT+05:45

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.